Orbax checkpointing using jit
I am running a Reinforcement Learning agent implented in Jax, using jit. Following this tutorial, I have tried to implemented checkpoints of the agent's training per few training steps.
However, I receive the folllowing error when trying to save the environment state (which is a jax.numpy array):
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

When I try to save the TrainState of the agent, I receive a much longer error, which ends with the following advice:
See https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/errors.html#jax.errors.ConcretizationTypeError

Is it possible to apply checkpoints in Traced Arrays when using jit? If so, do you have any advice?

Is it possible you are trying to save arrays from within a jitted function (which is not allowed behavior)? This could account for the ConcretizationTypeError, potentially.
Also worth providing a bit more context into your code, since I don't know where these errors, particularly the ValueError, are arising from.

This is true, I am trying to checkpoint from within a jitted function. I was not aware that this behvaiour is not possible. This means that I can only checkpoint outside this function (for saving my results after running). Is this correct?

Correct, you should perform the save after the jitted function runs.
And yes, looks like this requirement is not really documented anywhere - that should be fixed.

Thanks for your response. By the way, do you know any easy way of logging (exporting to json?) a JAX tracer within a jitted function? I have been trying to use jax.purecallback but with no result.
